# Why Nirjala Ekadashi is also known as Bhima Ekadashi?

Tags: bhima, ekadashi

Agiyaras in Jyaistha month is also known as Bhim Agiyaras. Why is the name of Bhim mentioned? 
any story of mango eating in Bhim Agiyaras?

Comment: https://www.drikpanchang.com/ekadashis/nirjala/nirjala-ekadashi-date-time.html

Comment: is Ekadashi called as Agiyaras in your local language? In our side it is called Gyarash as 11 is pronounced as Gyara...

Comment: Yes @YDS Ekadashi also called as Agiyaras in our local language

Comment: all ekadashi is supposed to be nirjal. but since we're unable to follow it, we choose at least one in a year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nirjala Ekadashi is also known as **Bhimseni** or **Bhima Ekadashi** due to one legend associated with Nirjala Ekadashi.

Bhimsen, the voracious eater, was not able to control his desire of having food. Due to this reason he was not able to observe Ekadashi fasting and met Maharishi Vyasa to find some solution.

> Sage Vyasa advised Bhima to observe single Nirjala Ekadasi fasting to compensate for not observing all Ekadashi fasting in a year. ~[nirjala-ekadashi-drikpanchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/ekadashis/nirjala/nirjala-ekadashi-date-time.html)

Due to this legend Nirjala Ekadashi is also known as Bhimseni Ekadashi.

The more detailed story is given [here](https://www.drikpanchang.com/ekadashis/nirjala/legends/hindi/nirjala-ekadashi-vrat-katha.html) (in Hindi) and in **PADMA-PURANA : UTTARAKHANDA : Chapter 51. Nirjala Ekadasi**.